# Is ad-hoc polymorphism a good practice in functional programming?

Tags: python, functional-programming, polymorphism

I am developing a utils data engineering package in python, and for the sake of reusability and readability, I chose the functional programming (FP) approach.

Assume a key task of converting data from types a, b, c to type X. I write three functions `from_a_to_x`, `from_b_to_x`, and `from_c_to_x`.

Is it a good practice in FP to have a `to_x` function such as:

```py
from typing import Union
from mypackage import from_a_to_x, from_b_to_x, from_c_to_x
from package_a import a
from package_b import b
from package_C import c

def to_x(data: Union[a, b, c]) -> x:
    """Converts data types a,b,c to x"""
    if isinstance(data, a):
        return from_a_to_x(data)
    elif isinstance(data, b):
        return from_b_to_x(data)
    elif isinstance(data, c):
        return from_c_to_x(data)
    else:
        raise TypeError("Unknown data type")
```

Or, this `to_x` function is unnecessary and the users should themselves handle the polymorphic behavior in their application?

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, `c` and `x` types you've implemented yourself? Are they builtin types? Provided by a third party package?

Comment: No, they are all imported from third-party packages or built-in types. For example, dict, datetime, etc.

Comment: There seems to be two different questions from your post: 1) _Is polymorphism a good practice in FP?_, and 2) _Is the specific implementation you provided good practice in Python?_. You seem to be more interested in the second one (and the first is quite broad, but can be summarized as "there are multiple kinds of polymorphism, but yes"). Could you clarify what are your expectations regarding answers?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not satisfied with my if-elif implementation. But, this was my only way of implementing polymorphic behavior and I wrote it to show what I'm doing. I'm more interested in knowing whether in FP, it's a good practice or not. However, if there are known ways to achieve polymorphism in FP python (pure functions without side effects), it would be great to know. People writing their applications using my utils function, should they handle it? Should I write `to_x`  to ease their work or is it not a good practice to do that in a package full of utils functions.

Comment: outside of to_x, do you ever have variables that can refer to an object of type a, b or c? dict and datetime seem like an odd couple to have a common abstraction

Comment: Consider a dict with keys of year, month, and day. I handle the logic of `to_x` in `from_dict_to_x` (consider x, for example a str of iso format datetime),  and in `from_datetime_to_x` I simply convert datetime to iso format. But, for your question, no global variables outside the scope of function are changed by these functions.

Comment: I'm with @VincentSavard here: the title of your question is unrelated to your actual question. There are multiple types of polymorphism, and they are very important in many functional languages. But because Python is dynamically typed, it can only support one type: ad-hoc polymorphism. And you aren't using that in your question.

Comment: You may be interested in Python 3.10's [pattern matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636). For a broader context, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch).

Comment: @J.G. switch case is a nice implementation, but I need my code to be compatible with older versions too.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe it'll help in the future, though.

Comment: What python versions do you want to support? If you can do >=3.4, you can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems to be a common cargo cult today to ask if something is *"a good practice"*. Usually, this is the wrong question, since in programming there is almost nothing "good" or "bad" per se - it always depends. So which "cons" and "pros" do you get by implementing a function like `to_x` in the shown way (compared to the alternative of not providing this function at all)?

Pros:

- it is simple
- you don't have to care for potentially unwanted side effects by modifying existing packages, classes or objects
- code which is implemented in terms of `to_x` works generically on all supported types

Cons:

- `to_x` violates the Open-Closed principle, which means, whenever the conversion logic needs to be extended for another type, you have to change `to_x`.

Is this a problem? This depends on how much genericity your code requires. When your goal is to put `to_x` into a package X, your generic code using `to_x` lives in another package Y, and you want to be able to introduce a new type `d` to work with Y without changing X, then this may become a problem, especially when all those packages have different maintainers. In this case, an OO solution might be better suited.  But if that's not your goal, and you just want to use `to_x` as some "syntactic sugar" for the conversion for a fixed number of types, then go ahead.

The OCP is not an end in itself, it is a means to an end, and for lots of real-world situations following it can lead to overengineering.

Comment: "Usually, this is the wrong question, since in programming there is almost nothing "good" or "bad" per se - it always depends." +100 on this if I could

Comment: _"It seems to be a common cargo cult today to ask if something is "a good practice"."_ - if by "today", you mean this and the previous decade. And possibly before, but that's when _I_ started programming and reading those questions.

Comment: A good practice is one that provides a good/acceptable general trade off in many scenarios (which doesn't mean it is always the best). It is a perfect valid strategy to go with good practices without fully evaluating each and every instance - until you really need to. Nothing cargo cultural about it, it's just a short cut in formulation - e.g. when one doesn't know all the aspects that one should consider - and in decision making (when one doesn't want to invest the time to think everything through and wants a reasonable default). Otherwise nice answer.

Comment: @FrankHopkins: when not having enough information for a full evaluation of a scenario , I recommend to use the **most simple** solution for a problem that works, and not something some architecture astronaut or "design patterns book writer" has declared to be a "best practice for many scenarios". So people should better stop to ask "what is the practice", but "what is the most simple, working approach", and at "at what point should I use a more complex one".

Comment: @R.Schmitz I think it goes back at least as far as Edsger Dijkstra's 1968 letter ‘[Go To Statement Considered Harmful’](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/362929.362947).

Comment: @R.Schmitz, and giidds: I agree to both of you, I can remember to have seen such line of thinking by myself >30 years ago. What I really had in mind here was the fact lots of askers *speficially on this site* seem to be in search for a "best practice" which can be applied without thinking about the context.

Comment: Although I appreciate your statement regarding the correctness of a question on what is a good or better practice, doing the simpler or faster way almost always leads to technical debt, low maintainability, and the need for refactoring. So, as a novice person in FP, I had to ask before experimenting. @Doc Brown

Comment: @maaniB: quite the opposite - overly complex solutions lead to technical debt, not simple solutions - at least what I call "simple", but I think the comment section here is too small to give you a comprehensive explanation.

Comment: @DocBrown By "simpler", I meant easier, not uncomplicated. It's obvious that complex implementations lead to technical issues. And something being difficult for someone might be due to lack of experience/knowledge, not the innate complexity of the subject matter. Static type analysis by tools like mypy, for instance, is difficult to learn and implement for beginners, but it's not complex and prevents future issues in a dynamically typed language. BTW, thank you for sharing your experience.

Comment: @maaniB It sounds like you have probably already seen it already, but in the chance you haven't yet, check out the talk Simple Made Easy by Rich Hickey. It gets into exactly this dichotomy of "easy" vs "simple". The original `to_x` with manual dispatch is a perfect example of "easy" (straightforward) but not "simple" (it entangles your implementation with every data type it can receive). True type classes "decouple the impl from the interface" so you don't care about what types come after you, and are thus "simpler" in the "simplex" sense of the word.

Comment: @DeusXMachina Insightful, I use the radon python package for measuring the complexity and maintainability of our code, and generating badges for the projects of my team. It is important to know, a function or method in a class should not make lots of decisions, following such a mindset leads to writing more atomic functions and methods which are reusable, easily testable, and maintainable.

Answer (score 8):

Statically typed functional programming languages often solve this situation with a [type class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class). For example, Haskell has a [Show](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Show) that converts type instances to a string, similar to your `to_x` if x was a string. The nice thing about type classes is you don't require one central function that knows about all the individual implementations.

So ad hoc polymorphism is not only a good practice in functional programming, many FP languages have more expressive ways of doing ad hoc polymorphism.

However, you're not using one of those languages, so you should use the most expressive mechanism that your language provides. That means something like [Caleth's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/433480/3965). Object-oriented classes do not conflict with a functional style. They can work very nicely together.

Avoiding OO classes at all costs is more of a procedural style than a functional style. If that's what you're going for, that's fine, but you're going to have situations like your `to_x` where it doesn't seem to fit well with the language.

Comment: To be honest, Caleth's solution does look more like an ugly hack to me, to simulate extension methods in Python. The OP's code is something I understand immediately.

Comment: @DocBrown `def` creates an object, and binds it to a name in a scope. The code in my answer takes an existing object and binds it to a name in a scope.

Comment: @DocBrown, extension methods are the simulation. Monkey patching is the older and more powerful technique. I very much prefer static typing, and even I have a hard time arguing those three lines in his first example aren't a prime example of the benefit of a dynamic language. It can't get much simpler.

Comment: The paper that introduces type classes is literally titled "How to make ad-hoc polymorphism less ad hoc".

Comment: @Caleth: ok, I have to admit, I think the solution which confused me was the one you stripped out of the answer in your [last edit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/433480/4). Your monkey patching approach is surely readable and simple, however, it isn't semantically equivalent to the original code.

Answer (score 4):

Polymorphism like this is painful in Python because it lacks function overloading.

Ideally you'd have overloads of `to_x` for each of `a`, `b` and `c`, and `Union` would dispatch to the correct overload when you use it, but that isn't Python.

If you want to avoid lots of `isinstance`, you could add `to_x` to each of `a, b, c` as a member

```
from typing import Union
from package import from_a_to_x, from_b_to_x, from_c_to_x

a.to_x = from_a_to_x
b.to_x = from_b_to_x
c.to_x = from_c_to_x

def to_x(data: Union[a, b, c]) -> x:
    return data.to_x()

# can call data.to_x() instead of to_x(data)
```

But you seem to be insistent on an `isinstance` approach. Might I suggest iterating your `if`s

```
_to_x = [ 
    (a, from_a_to_x),
    (b, from_b_to_x),
    (c, from_c_to_x)
]

def to_x(data: Union[a, b, c]) -> x:
    for typ, func in _to_x:
        if isinstance(typ, data):
            return func(data)
    raise TypeError("Unknown data type")
```

Comment: I don't want to use classes.

Comment: @maaniB every value in Python has a class. `int` is a class, `NoneType` is a class etc

Comment: Yes, but I cannot implement a method to_x for a built-in type like dict, simply by means of functions. I know that python is primarily object-oriented, but one can use FP principles. And, having side-effects is against those FP principles.

Comment: @maaniB either you use the polymorphism tools that Python provides, or *someone* has to write many `isinstance` checks

Comment: Obviously, polymorphism is easily handled in object-oriented python. The point of this question, for me, is that, considering FP principles of pure functions and having no side effects, one can achieve polymorphic behavior using if-elif conditions. However, I wanted to know whether in FP is it a good practice to have a function using those subfunctions? or the developers using this utils package should handle it, for example in their API.

Comment: @maaniB Like I said, *someone* is going to have to write your `do_x`. Whether that's you or clients of your package rather depends on the focus of your package. Is it all about `Union[a, b, c]`?

Comment: @maaniB Your code already has a great big side effect in it: `raise TypeError("Unknown data type")`

Comment: @maaniB `def` has a side-effect: it binds a name to a value in the current scope.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I thought raising errors and exceptions break referential transparency, but they're not side effects as they don't affect outside of the scope of function (I/O). I'm novice in FP, and thanks for pointing out the problems with exceptions. Considering exceptions as side-effect, the `to_x`  is a bad practice in FP.

Comment: @Caleth, I don't think defining a function is a side effect and against FP. Because we have to define functions somewhere in memory. We consider that a function has a side effect if it modifies a mutable data structure or variable, uses IO, throws an exception or halts an error; all of these things are considered side effects.

Comment: @maaniB what's special about the module objects (and the various locals objects in functions you declare) that means you can mutate them, and not class objects?

Comment: In FP, local variables, which are not accesible from outside the function, might be modified. Such as a function def f(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y which you can replace f(2, 2) with 4. It means they are deterministic, as they always return the same value for a given input. But, changing states of other objects or classes outside the function, it is procedural programming not FP.

Comment: @maaniB I mean [module objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html) and the result of [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals). You can't help but mutate those objects when writing Python

Comment: And by "class objects" I mean the object `a` that denotes the class, not instances of it.

Comment: @maaniB `a.to_x = from_a_to_x` is not "changing state of a class". It does implement a method, that's all - just like a `def` in that class would.

Comment: @Bergi `def` inside a class implements a method, obviously in an oop approach. However, when you use `a.to_x` for an external object, it is a side-effect to add a new method to the class `a`. In an FP approach, we do not want to change the behavior of other classes. We just use inputs, do some calculations, and return an output.

Comment: @maaniB It is an effect of setting up the module. It is not a side effect of calling the `to_x(data)` function, which is what FP is concerned with. Changing the behaviour of classes from other modules might go against modular programming practices, but it's what we're left with in Python. It does not go against the spirit of FP.

Comment: @Caleth You might even want to add a `def to_x(data): return data.to_x()` function to do the dynamic dispatch

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a pretty common thing to do in Python libraries.  I'd say it's an approach that works in practice but not in theory.  The biggest challenge it is not always obvious what types such methods take but you've mitigated that with typing hints to some level.

One thing you can do to eliminate the if-else chaining is to use a dict, like so:

```
converters = {
    a: from_a_to_x,
    b: from_b_to_x,
    c: from_c_to_x,
}


def to_x(data: Union[a, b, c]) -> x:
    try:
        return converters[type(data)](data)
    except KeyError:
        raise TypeError("Unknown data type")
```

Alternately, if you need to support subtypes, you can do this:

```
def to_x(data: Union[a, b, c]) -> x:
    for typ, converter in converters.items():
        if isinstance(data, typ):
            return converter(data)

    raise TypeError("Unknown data type")
```

The challenge with that, though is the order of the dict items might change your results.

The big advantage of this is that you can 'register' new converters at runtime instead of having to modify the code.  Of course, your type hints won't be of much use if you allow for that.  Personally I still prefer this over the if-else chain, all things equal.

Comment: The (possible) downside of using a dictionary of types exactly like this is that it does not allow for covariant of the type. Sometimes you want that, but often times when it comes to converters, if you have something which turns an `A` to an `X`, you can usually do the same thing to `ChildOfA`.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for `functools.singledispatch`. I just learned about type classes literally 20 minutes ago, and went looking to see if python could support them. I found singledispatch (which is *almost* like typeclasses, almost) and this post.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch

This decorator allows you to write your library-specific implementations, while allowing them to be extended:

```
from typing import Union
from functools import singledispatch
from maaniB import from_a_to_x, from_b_to_x, from_c_to_x
from package_a import a
from package_b import b
from package_C import c

@singledispatch
def to_x(data) -> x:
    raise NotImplementedError(f"Unhandled data type: {type(data)}" 

to_x.register(a, from_a_to_x)
to_x.register(b, from_b_to_x)
to_x.register(c, from_c_to_x)
```

The great part about this is that it allows me, a consumer, to implement my own types, without any input from you, the library maintainer:

```
from maaniB import to_x

@to_x.register
def int_to_x(i):
    return whatever(i)

class MyOwnWidget:
    def to_x(self):
        return f"MyOwn({self})"
    
to_x.register(MyOwnWidget, MyOwnWidget.to_x)
```

If you can use python >=3.8, you can also use `singledispatchmethod`.

## Why is this better?

To understand the advantages of this approach, we first have to briefly consider what the alternatives are. The first is inheritance-based polymorphism. If you wanted, you could write the `elif isinstance` tree in a OOPy way.

In python, the difference between `Widget(foo).to_x()` (instance method with `self`) and `Widget.to_x(foo)` (the unbound method) is very small. So as long as you control type `a`, you can just write a `A.to_x()` method. If there is significant similarity, you can often accomplish this behavior with a mixin. This is "early binding". The one great thing about this approach is that it facilitates generic interfaces and static type checking.

You can provide a `AbstractBaseClass` and let the user implement their own `to_x` but this tends to lead to the [banana-gorilla-jungle problem](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/07/19/you-wanted-banana/) with more sophisticated interfaces.

However, it sounds like from your setup that `package_a` through `_c` are not actually libraries you control. Hence why you end up with the function with the manual type dispatch. As Doc Brown points out, this could be fine if the set of types you wish to handle is small - e.g. you just want to deal with numpy arrays and pandas dataframes. By using runtime dispatch, you don't have to modify the actual library code. This is "late binding". This works great when you are converging on a single concrete type (say you are returning `str`), but it gets more tricky if the return type is parametric. Say your `to_x` is tasked with converting all custom types to `Union[str, int, float, dict, list]` so you can JSON serialize it later. But you don't know whether the root object is a `Dict` or `List` until you get your actual object. You need to essentially loosen the return type so that the type checks out. But now you have this abomination like `-> Union[Dict[str, Jsonable], List[Dict[str, Jsonable]]` (where Jsonable is roughly `Union[list, dict, int, float, str, type(None)]`. Also lets say a new type arrives and the sensible interface is to return a primitive, now you have `-> Union[Jsonable, Dict[str, Jsonable], List[Dict[str, Jsonable]]`, it's a hot mess. It would be nice if each implementation could have its own return type, based on the input type. And as mentioned, late binding suffers from downsides relating to OCP.

`singledispatch` *mostly* avoids issues with OCP; it's not quite the same type class behavior as more FP-heavy languages since you have to explicitly register functions. But I would contend that it gives you the best of both worlds - the stronger type guarantees of early binding, but the dynamicism of late binding.

Answer (score 2):

Ad hoc polymorphism is used in FP, but your example isn't really a case where this is the way to go.

Rather, it is a very clear-cut example of an *algebraic data type*. In Haskell, you'd do it like this:

```hs
import MyPackage (fromAtoX, fromBtoX, fromCtoX)
import PackageA (A)
import PackageB (B)
import PackageC (C)

data ABC = Aey A
         | Bee B
         | Sea C

toX :: ABC -> X
toX (Aey a) = fromAtoX a
toX (Bee b) = fromBtoX b
toX (Sea c) = fromCtoX c
```

Those multiple *clauses* you can have in Haskell are nothing but alternative syntax for the perhaps more familiar-looking

```hs
toX datas = case datas of
     Aey a -> fromAtoX a
     Bee b -> fromBtoX b
     Sea c -> fromCtoX c
```

Python's `Union` is essentially expressing the *sum type* `ABC`, and the `isinstance` cases correspond to the different case-matches / clauses. The difference is that in Python the type is *always* part of a value's runtime representation, so you might as well use it for the branch selection, whereas in Haskell types are normally erased at runtime but you can explicitly distinguish different cases. This has several advantages (including that the compiler can easier check correctness&completeness, as well as optimising the decisions, and you can add further special cases without needing additional types), but it does require that when *calling* `toX`, you need to explicitly wrap the value in its dedicated constructor, like

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
   let myA = ...
   let myX = toX (Aey myA)
   print myX
```

Real ad-hoc polymorphism is also possible in Haskell, done with *type classes* (this is perhaps surprising from an OO background); in your example it would be

```hs
class XAble d where toX :: d -> X

instance XAble A where toX = fromAtoX
instance XAble B where toX = fromBtoX
instance XAble C where toX = fromCtoX
```

In this case, there is no need to wrap the values, however this is in practice quite different from how your Python example is structured, because the type class is *open*, i.e. anybody might later on add new types that can be converted to `X`, whereas in your case you restrict the allowed types to exactly `A`, `B` and `C` – again, that is like a Haskell sum type, not like a Haskell typeclass.

Comment: awesome!  I noticed you didn't raise errors, manually. How do FP langs like Haskell handle errors? Does Haskell return errors at runtime for an unknown type d? And What do you think about returning null types, in python we may return Union[x, None] or Optional[x] if we don't want to raise exceptions.

Comment: That's one of the advantage of the `ABC` sum type: it's not even _possible_ to generate a value of a type that's not listed in the `data` declaration – you would need another constructor with type `D -> ABC`, but the only constructors are those that you've already listed. If you have a variable `d :: D` and try to write e.g. `toX (Bee d)` then you'll get a _compiler_ error, which can never surface at runtime.

Comment: ...but that's not to say Haskell never needs to handle errors. Indeed one of the possibilities is `Optional`, which is called [`Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Maybe) in Haskell. And you can always [raise exceptions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:throw) (Haskell is not _total_, in contrast to languages like Agda), but this should preferrably only be done if some IO operation failed that you couldn't possibly have planned for, or something truely “impossible” (so you thought) has happened.